# Angular two-way binding not woking in template-driven forms

Tags: angular, ngmodel

I am trying to read a property from the class in my template-driven form but there's no way of making it work. This is my class:

```
...
export class IdComponent implements OnInit {
      title : String = "Edit user";
...
```

And this is my form

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="title1" [(ngModel)]="this.title">
    <input type="text" id="title2" value = "{{ this.title }}">
</form>
```

First input works but second doesn't. What am I doing wrong? Here's an evidence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwc5E.jpg)

Comment: There is no double bind in the second input

Comment: The `title` should be of type `string` not `String`, because `String` is only for strings created with `String('hello')` syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html should look like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="title" />
  <input type="text" value="{{ title }}">
</form>
```

Or in other words you need to add `name` attribute to input with `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: That was the point!! I Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 'this.' from [(ngModel)] and value just leave it simple "title"

```
[(ngModel)]="title"
[value]="title"
```

Comment: If you use attributes with Angular syntax for binding you don't need to use curly brackets.

Comment: trueee.. it was my mistake.. that would show an error. Thanks!